# Should Phantom Liberty and Cyberpunk 2077 2.0/2.1 tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Cyberpunk 2.0 and 2.1 added some major changes to the base game of Cyberpunk 2077.

There's *significant* changes - the crafting and hacking/netrunning mechanics have had revamps, there's entirely different skill trees and vehicular combat is different. There's also the metro system in 2.1. Essentially while the 'story' and missions are not changed, the gameplay mechanics are often going to be different from when one plays cyberpunk 1.x.

You can, in theory download 'older' builds of cyberpunk so if you want to play the 'older' builds of the game its plausible - not sure why though, considering the 'reputation' it had

Phantom Liberty getting its own tag for its DLC content makes sense.
Should we be updating cyberpunk 1.x questions for 2.0 or giving 2.0/2/1 its own tag?

Comment: The Phantom Liberty expansion is not free - are the changes applied to the base game without paying for the expansion?

Comment: @Robotnik I believe the updates to the base game are for everyone. the DLC is just additional quests/storyline/etc.

Comment: Yup!  2.0 is the 'new' mechanics, including a revamped perks/skills tree, a very different, non skill based crafting system and so on.  2.1 adds... a metro/slow travel system

Comment: Related discussions RE: obsolete questions to fill the sidebar: [Dealing with old questions about non-existent features?](https://meta.arqade.com/q/14661), [Should we be undeleting questions that weren't relevant at the time, but now are relevant again?](https://meta.arqade.com/q/10580), ['Too Localised' is no longer a valid close reason, can we review these two popular Diablo 3 posts that were closed as such?](https://meta.arqade.com/q/11813), [What should be done with out of version questions?](https://meta.arqade.com/q/5727/28182)

Answer (score 5):

For new patches or updated games that remain the same game, I don't recall us ever creating a new tag. Many live service games frequently change/add/remove mechanics in patches which invalidates some old answers, in which case the answers need to be updated or a new answer posted (good targets for placing bounties on). If it was a remaster it would be worth creating a new tag, but for an update, using the same tag is fine.

For DLC's we do typically use a new tag. See [skyrim-dawngaurd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-dawngaurd) or [civilization-6-gathering-storm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-6-gathering-storm). In this case, I would create the tag: [cyberpunk-2077-phantom-liberty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyberpunk-2077-phantom-liberty) for the DLC as it fits within the 35 character limit for tags and follows the tagging convention of other DLC tags.

Comment: Yep, this is the best approach. Regarding old questions about outdated mechanics - update the answers if the change is minor (e.g. a Perk changing from a 10% buff to a 15% buff, an edit would be appropriate), write a new answer if it's a major overhaul, downvote and comment answers that are (now) incorrect or unsalvageable. Continue to use the base tag for all questions, and the DLC tag for DLC-specific content only.

Comment: I'd say a good chunk of the No Man's Sky questions I had asked/answered back in the day aren't really relevant anymore, as the game has changed so much. But they're still questions for the original game, even if they don't exactly apply 7 years later.